# How to configure environment parameter TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

BH

I'm using gazebo 2.2.5 version with Ubuntu TRUSTY. I would like to launch the turtlebot_world.launch file in order to operate a turtlebot with the  kobuki_keyop package in an empty world. While launching the file, I get this error:
Invalid  tag: environment variable 'TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE' is not set.

Arg xml is 
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

How can I set the TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE parameter so that the command will work?

Seeking forward for ones help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208287/how-to-configure-environment-parameter--turtlebot_gazebo_world_file/) by [Haz88](https://answers.ros.org/users/22113/haz88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-05-01

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-05-13**:
Have you installed `ros-indigo-turtlebot-gazebo`?

**Comment by [abhay2302](https://answers.ros.org/users/28289/abhay2302/) on 2016-12-15**:
open a new terminal and than try. hope that may work.

**Comment by [jaskaranvirdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29882/jaskaranvirdi/) on 2017-04-04**:
It did work after opening the terminal again. Maybe because the environment variable wasn't loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It asks for a world file, so give it a world file. Something like

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch world_file:=/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world
```

---

Originally posted by [Girts L](https://answers.ros.org/users/3081/girts-l/) with karma: 196 on 2016-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-09-27**:
This MAY work for now, but you should really stick to the way the package developers support. See the link in [my answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/208287/how-to-configure-environment-parameter-turtlebot_gazebo_world_file/?answer=216903#post-id-216903).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turtlebot utilizes environment variables that are set by env hook. See [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation#Environment_variables).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-09-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use the folowing command

rosmake turtlebot_gazebo

it will build the packages installed

---

Originally posted by [InderpreetSingh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28075/inderpreetsingh/) with karma: 51 on 2016-09-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danielsnider](https://answers.ros.org/users/29280/danielsnider/) on 2017-04-23**:
Worked for me in kinetic:

```
export TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```